# Why is Game Center matchmaking controller stuck on "connecting"?

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit

Trying to solve a Game Center issue that seems to be happening within the `GCMatchmakerViewController`, but maybe I'm somehow causing it. There are two ways to match to players via the Invite Friends button: by typing their email (or selecting from contacts) or by tapping from presented list of people played with recently.

If I select via the list of people played with recently, a notification is sent to them, and if they accept, the app launches, goes to the proper screen, presents the `GCMatchmakerViewController`, connects, accepts, and away we go with the game.

If I select by typing/selecting their contact, an iMessage is sent, they go to Messages, tap the message bubble. If the game app is already running, it is brought to foreground, `GCMatchmakerViewController` is presented, connects, accepts, and away we go. But if the app is not running, it launches, goes to proper screen, presents `GCMatchmakerViewController`, tries connecting, and just sits there forever.

Why is the connection not happening in that latter scenario?

The screen that is displayed when it's stuck connecting is this:

[image: GVMatchmakingViewController]

The code that presents the vc that issues the invitation:

```
    let localPlayer: GKLocalPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.local

    if localPlayer.isAuthenticated {
            let matchrequest = GKMatchRequest()
            matchrequest.minPlayers = 2
            matchrequest.maxPlayers = 4
            matchrequest.defaultNumberOfPlayers = 2
            matchrequest.inviteMessage = "Want to play: " + "some name"

            if let mmVC = GKMatchmakerViewController(matchRequest: matchrequest) {
                mmVC.matchmakerDelegate = self
                self.present(mmVC, animated: true)
            }
    }
```

The code that accepts the invitation:

```
                    if let response = GKMatchmakerViewController.init(invite: invite) {
                        response.matchmakerDelegate = newGameVC
                        present(response, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
```

Best as I can tell, my app doesn't know which scenario is in play, and does not choose different behaviors based on that. Stumped, and not sure how to advise users. Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? Currently experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I've refactored the code to eliminate every potential complication I can imagine, while still retaining app features, and it's still case where match is not made iff the app is not already launched on invitee's device when invitation via Messages is accepted. If app is active, or even in background, or if invitation is via notification from Game Center id, match is successful. Submitted it as Bug Report, with only response being to maybe use a TSI, which would be a nightmare to create if trying to strip out code unrelated to this particular issue, if that makes sense...